# Select rows based on hierarchical permissions

Tags: sql

I have a tree/hierarchy of groups and a SQL table of items,each associated with a group (ie. each item belongs to a group). I need to select only the rows associated with a given group, or with the groups below.

eg. say this is the group tree:

```
A
 => B
     => D
 => C
     => E
     => F
```

Selecting items for group A will return all rows, while selecting for group C will select items belonging in C,E and F (descendants of C).

So far, I am thinking I can implement this in one of two ways:

**1. IN list**

```
SELECT * FROM table WERE Group in ('C','E','F')
```

programatically determining the list of descendants before querying

**2. BITWISE operator**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE GroupBitMask &  52!=0
```

(ie.  bitwise 'C' + 'E' + 'F' ==bit 3 + bit 5 + bit 6 == 110100 ==52 )

again, this 52 will need to be computed before the query by parsing the group tree.
I guess I can probably enforce a limit of 64 groups max. and use a 64-bit mask for this.

I'm not sure if the database will use an index for this or simply scan all rows to determine the bitwise result?

Are there any other (better?) methods of selecting the rows I need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to store the ancestry as part of the row:

```
Group     Path    Other columns
A         A       ...
B         AB      ...
C         AC      ...
D         ABD     ...
E         ACE     ...
F         ACF     ...
```

You can retrieve the base path with single query:

```
select Path from YourTable where Group = 'C'
```

Then you can query all descendants like:

```
select * from YourTable where path like 'AC%'
```

This performs very well with a primary key on `(Group)` and an index on `(Path)`.